# JTextArea Rounded corners Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea, rounded-corners

I would like to know how it is possible to do a JTextArea and a JTextField with rounded corners and rounded borders (I am using java swing)

Thank you very much.

Regards

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Border roundedBorder = new LineBorder(Color.green, 5, true); // the third parameter - true, says it's round
someTextArea.setBorder(roundedBorder);
```